# My cat is not sleeping at night since I switched to a night shift job

Tags: cats, behavior, sleep

I recently took up a night shift job. Since then my cat is behaving strangely.

My cat is used to sleeping on my bed by my side. I use her as side pillow.

But since I took the job, my mother says she sits all night in front of front door and occasionally meows. And she sniffs my home slippers kept in shoe rack.

How to make her sleep at night again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can take your t-shirt that you have used for the day and put it on the cat's bed. This makes your cat more comfortable as your cat can smell you even if you are not there in person.

I have used this solution for many years when I worked in the night and had several cats.

(Some people say cats do ignore their owners but they don't as you will see if you try this little tip of mine).

Comment: Anyone who thinks a cat doesn't love its human has clearly never been a cat parent.